# Trying to get Mongo Compass working on CENTOS 7

Tags: mongodb, centos7, mongodb-compass

Attempting to install and run [Mongo Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/compass)  on two separate CENTOS 7 laptops, and it doesn't work in either one.

**Problem Description:**
Downloaded the Mongo Compass RPM for Red Hat 7 here: https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/compass
Installed it from the Downloads directory using

```
    sudo yum localinstall mongodb-compass-1.22.1.x86_64.rpm
```

*Note:* it installs successfully and a symlink appears in usr/share/applications.

I drag the symlink onto the desktop and click it.

*The symlink image bounces around for 10-20 seconds and then disappears.*

**My Fix Attempts**
I've tried numerous fixes, including:

1. Uninstall both Mongo and Mongo Compass & then reinstall Mongo first
   with no security or restrictions then Mongo Compass
2. Installing only
   Mongo Compass first without Mongo installed
3. Installing EPEL and
   updating all YUM repos and then re-trying
4. Opening up permissions to the executable using CHMOD

Nothing seems to do the trick, and I can't find any existing help or advice from others using CENTOS 7 and Mongo Compass.

Comment: after rpm installation do this
`sudo chmod 4755 /usr/lib/mongodb-compass/chrome-sandbox`

Comment: @vk-code your solution works:  Thanks for taking a look.  Not sure how you figured out that the chrome-sandbox directory needed permissions, so I am curious about how you tracked it down.  Regardless, thank you.

Comment: I myself faced this issue long back, i have kept this in my notes :) try running mongo-compass from terminal and may be that's where it shows exact above error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to mark this answered!

after rpm installation do this `sudo chmod 4755 /usr/lib/mongodb-compass/chrome-sandbox`